# tcl : grep xml file

Tags: xml, grep, tcl

I want to grep xml file which contains :

```
<name>
name1
</name>
<value>
val1
</value>
<name>
name2
</name>
<value>
val2
</value>
<name>
name3
</name>
<value>
val3
</value>
<name>
name4
</name>
<value>
val4
</value>
<name>
nameX
</name>
<value>
valX
</value>
```

I want to extract from file only name beteewn `<name>` and `</name>` tags

the desired result :

```
 name1
 name2
 name3
 name4
 nameX
```

I execute the following command

```
exec grep -e "\\<name\\>.*\\<\\/name\\>$" file
```

but I got `child process exited abnormally`

Comment: Is it possible for you to use `tdom`?  That would make it much cleaner to extract data from xml.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep without escaping for tcl:

```
grep -Poz '<name>\n\K.*(?=\n</name>)' file
```

Output:

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
nameX
```

Comment: The escaping for Tcl would give: `exec grep -Poz {<name>\n\K.*(?=\n</name>)} file` and would give the same result.

Comment: @DonalFellows: Thank you.